# Efficient algorithm for equation

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm

I want to ask about efficient algorithm.
Example i have equation :

```
x = y + z;
```

if the value of variable y = 1, variable  z = 2 so variable  x is 3

But how to get value of y automatically if variable x = 3 and variable z = 2 with that equation? without create new equation `y = x - z`

I hope can get sample code using C# or javascript.

Another example, if the equation is

```
a = (((x + y - z)/2)*10)^4
```

The equation is from program, user submit value of 3 varibles.
User submit variable (x, y, z) or (y, z, a) or (z, a, x) or (a, x, y)

if user input value for var x, y and z, program can displaying value of a with that equation. Without create a = ...

if user input value for var y, z and a, program can displaying value of x with that equation. Without create x = ...

if user input value for var z, a and x, program can displaying value of y with that equation. Without create y = ...

if user input value for var a, x and y, program can displaying value of z with that equation. Without create z = ...

Comment: use `if` or `switch` statements?

Comment: Will this equation ever be changed (hardcoded or dynamic)?  Does the user submit an equation?  If so, does error checking for the equation need to be implemented (accurate parenthesis, exponents, etc.)

Comment: @Jon : I have edited with new explanation, the equation is from program, user can't change, user just submit value of variables

Comment: FYI - Not sure if you meant `^4` as `power of 4`, but `^` in C# is the `XOR` operator. If you want power of, use the `Math.Pow(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an 'equation solver'. This is non-trivial and there is quite a bit of research on this and some well-known large mathematical software do this.

For more details, please google 'Algorithms for Computer Algebra'.

Comment: Okay, you catch my question. So, i have to manually create equation for each variable that i want to get the value? Thank you

Comment: That seems to be the easiest way. Equation solvers are non-trivial, and for your purposes what you will likely need is just a set of multiple equations.
Some equations may not even be solvable and there are many such complications which may be immaterial to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve the equations with respect to the unknown variable:

```
x = y + z;
```

is equivalent to

```
y = x - z;
```

and

```
z = x - y;
```

For the second equation it is more difficult. If a < 0 there will be no solution. Otherwise you can first take the 4th root:

```
a = (((x + y - z)/2)*10)^4   <=>  sqrt(sqrt(a)) = +/- (x + y + z) * 5
```

Then resolve it with respect to x, y or z. Note that you will get two solutions in general.

There are programs and libraries that can do these calculations automatically: Check for "symbolic math" or "computer algebra systems".

Answer (score 0):

i sense a deep research of math on that problem you present, you can serach on google about [equation algorithm solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_solving) that a link of wikipedia

Yes in case you have a simple workflow of some basic algorithm to find a variable

let us suppose this environment;
  since there are always going to be three variables,  you can valid that only one of the three is null and then select the equation of the variable you want to find if non are null then you send a message that no value are null

The original equation is x=y+z-a

```
x=5; y=7; z=2; a=null;

If (!x.hasValue ()){
 x= y + z - a;
} 
 ....
 Else if (!a.hasValue ()){
 a = -(x + y + a);
}Else{Console.Write("Don't give value to all variable");}
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't how it works. In programming languages you don't really have equations but rather assignments. You can assign a right-side value to the variable on the left side.

So the only way to obtain y, when having x and z is by running

```
y = x - z
```

EDIT: you may want to create something like

```
myFunction(double? x=null, double? y=null, double? z=null, double? a=null)
```

And then inside you check which variable is null (so not used), and perform your calculations accordingly. You would run it like this

```
var something = myFunction(x: 1, y: 2, a: 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to write a new line of code and get the result of 'y' when 'x' is diferent to zero within the same equation, try this ...

```
// equation : x = y + z
var x=3,y=0,z=2;
x = ((x!=0) ? (x-z) : y ) + z;
console.log("Result : "+ x);

// or saving the value in 'y'
x = ((x!=0) ? y = (x-z) : y ) + z;
console.log("Result 2 : "+ x);
```

Answer (score -2):

Answering the first question:

```
Y = X - Z
```

is the only possible solution. There aren't other ways to calculate Y. 
This because computers can't solve equations (or better, they can be programmed to solve them, but only using 'Y = X - Z') , they can change the value of a variable. In this case we set the Y value to (X - Z) value.

Answering the second question:

You can solve that equation doing

```
X = fourth square of (...)
```

or you can use libraries that do all this work by themselves, like 'computer algebra system' (Also cited by @FrankPuffer)

Definitely: you can solve the equations doing inverse operation, like 'Y = X - Z', or by using libraries that simplify writing code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have edited my question with new example

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, if you don't understand the question post a comment, and since you don't have the rep necessary to post a comment, wait for someone else to post a clarifying comment

Comment: @KevinWells I'm sorry... But this is the answr at the first question... He edited it later...

Comment: @EnricoBilla I understand that he added more to his question later, but you say directly in your answer "I haven't understood your question", which is a good reason not to post an answer

Comment: Yes, because at the first question, the only existing answer is that Y = X - Z, there are no other solution... I'll update my answer, answering to his second question! @KevinWells

Comment: Is the answer better now?  @KevinWells

Comment: @EnricoBilla You are still completely missing the point of his question, you say "computers can't solve equations", but that is completely untrue. They can't do that by default, but they can certainly be programmed to do so, which is exactly what he is trying to do. Providing answers to the specific equations he used as examples isn't useful to him solving the problem generally.

Comment: If it is not fixed now, I give up! @KevinWells

Comment: @EnricoBilla That's probably for the best because you don't seem to be listening to any of my critiques, and are instead just changing things that you think should be changed. Also, there is no need for another answer to this question at this point because it has been adequately covered by other people already

Comment: Ok, but I would not lose too much reputation for a mistake in my language... @KevinWells